# type "crystaldecisions.windows.forms.crystalreportviewer" is not defined

Tags: .net-4.0, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

Please help me on my problem. I am new with Crystal Reports.
I am using VS2010. .net Framework 4 client.

I have just installed **CRforVS13SP26_0-10010309.exe** but upon integrating in may form i got an error. please HELP me. Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I had to download "SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP29) installation package for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE" and update my project references.